# How Can I Refresh The Background Theme?

Tags: objective-c, swift3

[image: This Is My settings View Controller.]

I Will Going Done Two Things On It.

First set Theme colour On All VC and second changing my currency from INR TO USD or vice versa.

I Have This View Controller named As Settings VC.
1) I am going to change the theme of the VC
2) It will changed but for that I need to go back from this view controller. It              Will Never changed Here Automatically.
3) Can Anyone Help me For this to change it here automatically without navigating any other VC?

Here I Is My Code...

```
import UIKit

class SettingsVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var themeColorSeg: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var Currency: UISegmentedControl!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
        setThemeOnVC(View: self.view)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()     
        themeColorSeg.selectedSegmentIndex = getTheme()
        Currency.selectedSegmentIndex = getCurrency()
    }

    @IBAction func saveAction(_ sender: Any) {
        setTheme(themeCode: themeColorSeg.selectedSegmentIndex)
        setCurrency(CurrencyCode: Currency.selectedSegmentIndex)
        navigationController?.present(Utilities().configPopup(title: "Saved",     message: "Settings Seved Successfully!"), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }  
}
```

### [Check Video Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9qdY2qiE70AZDRxdzFsMWRaQlE/view)

Comment: I was uses getter and setter methods to get and set theme but in settings VC when I was click on save button it was not change on this VC for that first I need to go back then it will change!
In Short It Will not refresh VC after saving My settings.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9qdY2qiE70AZDRxdzFsMWRaQlE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: visit above video link for exact problem understanding..

Comment: in above video you can see when I change the settings it will not change automatically on that VC I need to go Back to Home VC And Then It Will Change..!


Can Anyone Help Me To Solve This Problem!

Answer (score 0):

on `saveAction`, add below line too

```
setThemeOnVC(View: self.view)
```